# JSON only allows one top level value?

Tags: java, json, parsing, gson

I have the following `Java` Object:

```
public class PersonDetails {
    private Person person;
    private List<Relative> relatives;

    public PersonDetails() {};

    //getters and setters

    }
```

I am trying to create Stub `JSON` for this so that I can parse it to a Java Object using `GSON`.

When I try to use the below JSON, but I get the error:

```
JSON only allows one top level value
```

How can I alter my `JSON` to make it valid?

My Current JSON:

```
{
    "Person": {

        "id": "123",
        "name: "stubName"
    },
    [
     "Relative": {

        "name": "relative1",
        "relation: "mother"

     }

    ]
}
```

Comment: you can get this error if you are trying to add a typescript file w/ data in it but have misnamed the file .json.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think your JSON structure is incorrect, GSON is expecting something like:

```
{
  "person": {
      // Person object
  },
  "relatives": [ // Mind the plural!
      {
           //Relative object
      },
      {
           //another Relative object
      }
  ]
}
```

Rationale: In general any JSON library will examine your beans looking for  public setters. If you have a setter like `setPerson(Person p)`, then it will remove the "set" prefix and then will switch the case of the next letter ("P" becomes "p"), so it will try to create a `Person` object and then insert it in a `person` attribute.

But then again I think there is something else wrong: that error complains that you have a JSON string like: `"{....},{....}"`, so you have 2 or more top level (aka root) objects, which is not allowed in the JSON standard notation.

Comment: This was my issue, my JSON structure was incorrect.

Answer (score 3):

You should check your JSON using a validator. [JsonLint](https://jsonlint.com/) is one.

This will show you that your JSON is invalid. There are a couple of problems.

Firstly you have unclosed quotes - `"name:` and `"relation:`.

Secondly, there's a more fundamental problem, which is that a JSON object can only contain a list of named fields. You have:

```
{  
   "field1" : "Value 1",
   [
       { ... an array element ... }
   ]
}
```

So you're trying to have a named field, and an unnamed array. That's not allowed.

You can fix this by giving the array field a name:

```
{  
   "field1" : "Value 1",
   "field2" : [
       { ... an array element ... }
   ]
}
```

Now the top level element contains two fields - `field1` which is a string, and `field2` which is an array.

Answer (score 0):

'Relatives' could be your field name and the list will be a javascript array with the element you need, like this:

```
{
    "Person": {

        "id": "123",
        "name: "stubName"
    },

    "Relatives": [{

            "name": "relative1",
            "relation: "mother"

         } ]
 }
```